# Nodejs fs.ensureDir if there's a file, replace with dir

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Say if I save something in a file: `/group1/sub1 [file]`

and then call fs.ensureDir on `/group1/sub1/subsub1/test [dir]`

Node will throw `Error: ENOTDIR: not a directory` and not continue.

Is there a way to replace the file with a directory when calling fs.ensureDir

Comment: Could you check if it is a file / directory first? You use fs.stats. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats

Comment: You could remove the file first [`fs.unlinkSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_unlinksync_path) and then put a folder [`fs.mkdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_options)

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'path' module to get the basename:

```
path.basename(path.dirname(filename))
```